# How to trim off Mr. or Ms. or Miss in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

How to trim off Mr. or Ms. or Miss in SQL server. Also I need to check only if Mr. or Ms. or Miss is available then only I need to trim.

Mr. Andy J Jones

Ms. Sarah D Lee

Miss Sarah D Lee

Comment: What about Mr or Ms without the periods? And these values ALWAYS at the beginning?

Comment: yes always at Beginning and has period but Miss does not have any period

Comment: So ONLY those three values? You don't have any data with "Ms Sarah D Lee" where there is no period? And what have you tried?

Comment: Yes only these three values

Comment: @user1030181, at least that is probably a good indication that the data will follow a consistent pattern - because to view "Mr" as an abbreviation of a title which requires a period, but "Miss" as an unabbreviated title, requires very subtle mind!

Comment: can we use case statement?

Comment: Of course you can use a case expression. Why wouldn't you be able to? Have you tried anything here?

Comment: If data is intentionally stored in the database like this, then it's a violation of 1st Normal Form.  Data should not have to be 'unpacked', where the first part of the string is analyzed.  Also, there are also different formats (Ms. versus Miss).  A design that complies with 1NF would be fields [FirstName], [LastName], and [Title].  Then, you could just select [FirstName] and [LastName] to avoid including the [Title].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

**SOLUTION**

```
SELECT a , SUBSTRING(a,CHARINDEX(' ',a,0),LEN(a)) NewformattedColumns FROM 
(
    SELECT 'Mr. Andy J Jones' a UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Ms. Sarah D Lee' a UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Miss Sarah D Lee'
)x
```

**OUTPUT**

```
a                NewformattedColumns
---------------- -------------------
Mr. Andy J Jones  Andy J Jones
Ms. Sarah D Lee   Sarah D Lee
Miss Sarah D Lee  Sarah D Lee

(3 rows affected)
```

**You need to use like below**

SELECT * , SUBSTRING(yourcolName,CHARINDEX(' ',yourcolName,0),LEN(yourcolName)) NewformattedColumns FROM YourtableName

Comment: But I have just one column value. so I am not planning to do union for this

Comment: They have that UNION ALL to generate the data. They don't have the table that you have. This be like selecting from your existing table.

Comment: I have updated the solution for you. Check this "You need to use like below"

Comment: This really doesn't quite work. You have an extra space in the new column. And if the value doesn't have one of those prefixes it returns incorrect values. Try adding a new row with 'first last' and you will see what I mean.

Comment: @How to trim off extra space

Comment: SELECT * , LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(yourcolName,CHARINDEX(' ',yourcolName,0),LEN(yourcolName)))) NewformattedColumns FROM YourtableName

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that all of your rows have ONE of the titles (Mr., Ms., or Miss), and you know that all of those also have a space after them, then searching for the space character and selecting the substring after that will work ok. If you have rows that do NOT have a title, then that will not work.

Another possible approach would be to use REPLACE:

```
SELECT REPLACE(ColName, 'Mr. ', '') FROM myTable
```

This has problems as well.  If somebody's first name contains the string "miss" at the end, this will give bad results.

Basically without checking every row, you cannot guarantee integrity. I'd agree with Zorkolot's comment, this data model needs to be fixed, if possible.